# How do I listen for progress updates on animator that shows and hides status bar - or where can I find more information?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-windowmanager, android-statusbar

In my activity, I hide and show the status bar using View.setSystemUIVisibility(int flags). I would like to translate my header at the same rate as the status bar comes in and goes out, so it looks like the status bar is pushing the header down.

I have registered a View.SystemUIVisibilityChangelistener but that doesn't give any progress updates.

Is there a way to get progress updates as the status bar changes state between visible and invisible?

If that's not possible, could someone please point me to the class that controls the status bar's entry and exit animation so I can find the parameters for the animator and use the same parameters to translate my header?

I show the status bar this way

```
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULL_SCREEN | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
```

and hide it this way

```
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Thanks!

Comment: So for clarification, your issue is that you don't want your header to enter AFTER the status bar is completely shown, but at the same time in which the status begins to enter the screen? I think I have an idea but I'll need a moment to test it out.

Comment: Yes, @ShaneDuffy that's what I'd like to do. I want it to look like how aToolBar in a CoordinatorLayout pushes recyclerviews and everything else down smoothly. Thanks for helping. Looking forward to hearing more about your idea

Comment: Could you include the flags  that you set?

Comment: @ShaneDuffy - I've added the code to the question. Thanks!